# What is the standard InvoiceID for a Ripple Bitcoin bridge?

Tags: transactions, ripple, address, ripple-gateways

In Ripple, bridges often encode a Bitcoin address as an InvoiceID in a transaction. According to [Services API wiki page](https://ripple.com/wiki/Services_API#Payments), InvoiceID is represented as UInt256, so it should be padded. Which is the standard way of padding the InvoiceID?

For example, having an address in hex form - `00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F6`

- According to [this code](https://gist.github.com/justmoon/5886477), the address should be padded on the right, like `00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F60000000000000000000000`
- If one submits a transaction to rippled without the padding, it gets padded on the left, like `000000000000000000000000010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F6`

Comment: Note that although the wiki (probably outdated) says that the InvoiceID is an encoded Bitcoin address, a more recent [post](https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=4059&p=21309&hilit=InvoiceID#p21309) by the an RL employee states that the InvoiceID is whatever the bridge provider sets it to. I.e. they can use whatever encoding or internal identifier they wish.

Comment: The standard implementation is [available on github](https://gist.github.com/justmoon/5886477) and this is what Bitstamp currently uses, but in principle a bridge can use any scheme they wish.